# How do I return a value from a promise to my calling function?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

The way I understand it is that I'm calling a synchronus function "httpGet" which is supposed to be returning a promise.  The function appears to be working because it is sucessfully getting all my data from the Airtable via the console.log statements, but I'm getting any response in the .then() method.

**Here's where I call the "httpGet" function:**

```
async handle(handlerInput) {
    let speechText = '';
    console.log('Going to fetch Airtable data');
    await httpGet(base).then((response) => {
      console.log('have promise')    
    }).catch((err) => {
      //set an optional error message here
      console.log('do not have promise')
      //speechText = 'there is an error ' + err.message;
    }); 
    speechText = `Container ID ` + contID + ` is a ` + bincolor + `, ` + gallons + ` located in ` + binloc ;        

    console.log('speechText = ' + speechText);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Warehouse Inventory', speechText)
      .getResponse();
};
```

**And here's the httpGet function that's being called:**

```
async function httpGet(options) {
  // return new pending promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    

        base('Bins').select({
          // Selecting a record in Grid view:
          maxRecords: 1,
          view: "Grid view"
        }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
          // This function (`page`) will get called for each page of records.

          records.forEach(function(record) {
              console.log('Container ID: ', record.get('Container ID'));
              console.log('Gallons: ', record.get('Gallons'));        
              console.log('Bin Color: ', record.get('Color'));
              console.log('Location: ', record.get('Location'));        
              console.log('Imperfections: ', record.get('Imperfections'));
              var contID = record.get('Container ID');
              var gallons = record.get('Gallons');
              var bincolor = record.get('Color');
              var binloc = record.get('Location');
              var imper = record.get('Imperfections');

          });

          // To fetch the next page of records, call `fetchNextPage`.
          // If there are more records, `page` will get called again.
          // If there are no more records, `done` will get called.
          fetchNextPage();

      }, function done(err) {
          if (err) { 
            console.error(err); return; 
          }
      });    
  });
}
```

Ultimately,I'm trying to grab the values stored in the varaibles contID, gallons, bincolor, binloc, and imper.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: The promise in `httpGet` is never resolved, so it can’t return a value; vkarpov15 has the solution. Note that in `handle`, you don’t need to chain `then` and `catch`; `await` lets you treat promises as if they were synchronous code, and you can use `try`/`catch` around `await`. Additionally, you can leave the `async` off `httpGet`, as it doesn’t use `await` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `httpGet()`, do `resolve({ contID, gallons, /* ... */ })`, and then in `then((response) => {})` your `response` will be an object with `contID`, `gallons`, etc. properties. Check out [this blog post](https://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js.html#return-values-and-exceptions) for more details on async return values.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has so much nesting, it's a bad practice. You can't return value from from a promise because it is asynchronous, you do what you want inside of it.

```
    httpGet = (options) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(/*return your result here*/);
        reject(/*return error here*/);
    });
}


//inside of some function
let firstResult, secondResult;
httpGet(argument)
    .then(result => {
        firstResult = result;
        //you can chain promise if u need
        return httpGet(secondArgument)
    })
    .then(result => {
        secondResult = result;
    })
    .then(() => {
        //here you can acces firstResult, secondResult variables, pass them to some function as arguments
    })
    .catch((error)=>{})
```